# Checking to see if a specific string is in a file txt

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a specific string is in a file text

so i have this file that contains the following:

```
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)        rxbytes    txbytes
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50860      72.21.91.29.http       CLOSE_WAIT         892        691
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50858      www.v.dropbox.co.https ESTABLISHED      27671       7563
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.6.50857      162.125.17.1.https     ESTABLISHED      17581       3642
```

and here is my code:

```
char = ""
file = open("location")

for  i, line in enumerate(file):
        addi = i + 1
        if line.strip() == char:
                print "MATCH FOUND on line " + str(addi)

print "finished"
```

For this to work, I have to paste the entire line in my `char` var. For example, it works if I paste "Active Internet connections", but If I put "Internet", it goes straight to the `print "finished"` line.  How would I fix this?

Comment: You are doing a complete match with `==`, instead use `in`, e.g. `if char in line.strip():`, which will return any lines which **contain** the string `char`.

Comment: You could split the line on spaces, then use `==` to compare words. I doubt you want to check if `"net con"` or `"gn Addr"` is in your file, for example.

Comment: You have to specify your goals a bit more, like do you want to search for whole words, or a partial match is still good (like "STAB" in "ESTABLISHED")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for contains (`in`) rather than equals (`==`). You can also use a list comprehension to get all the matches then print out the results:

```
char = "<search-string>"
with open("location") as file:
    results = [i for i, line in enumerate(file, 1) if char in line]

if results:
    print "MATCHES FOUND on lines " + ', '.join(results)

print "finished"
```

If you need more complicated search rules, then you may want to look at the regex module [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 2):

Might want to try using `with open() as` for proper file-handling.

And using the `in` keyword will work better than `==` because you want a match if it *contains* your string.

Also, using `str.format` is more readable IMO than `"stuff" + str(value)`

```
find = "Active Internet connections"
with open('location') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if find in line:
            print("Match found on line {}".format(i))

print("finished")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, strings are nothing more than lists of characters. To check if a string exists in another, you can use the in operator.

```
if char in line:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as `char in line`.

Example usage is that `"hi" in "hit"` will be `True`, and `"hi" in "hello"` will be `False`.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the `line` is in `char`, but you should do the reverse, since the entire line isn't in the `char`:

```
for  i, line in enumerate(file):
        line_index = i + 1
        if char in line:
                print "MATCH FOUND on line " + str(line_index)

print "finished"
```

also, I would recommend not to use `char` as a variable name. try to use more explicit and less ambiguous names like `pattern_to_find`

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a sub-string in Python is very simple task. Python's methods `find()` and `count()` are very useful in this context.

```
# This is the string you're looking for
ip = "192.168.1.6.50860"

# You need to do both, open and read file, to get its content
file = open("/home/my/own/directory/here/file.txt").read()

def findLine(text, string):
    if string in text:
        return "MATCH FOUND on line {}".format(text[0, text.find(string)].count("\n") + 1)
    else:
        return "MATCH NOT FOUND"

print(findLine(file, ip)) # Prints 3 (1-based indexing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
search = "what you want to find goes here"
filename = "file to read"
with open(filename) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if search in line:
            print "MATCH FOUND in line", i
```